# Skip the five second pre video intro videos on Iplayer?

Tags: iplayer

On BBC iPlayer, How do can I skip the five second pre-video videos?

Comment: This is likely against their Terms of Service.

Comment: @Dez I'm not sure about that, the BBC get's it's revenue from basically a TV Tax (TV Licence) in the UK, and as such has no reason to restrict that.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Reading through the TOS and Additional Terms it doesn't explicitly say anything about blocking or skipping portions like the Youtube TOS does.